# How to find records in a MYSQL table, that meet certain "criteria" in a different table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do something that is very complex for a beginner like my self. 
I have three MYSQL tables: "books", "categories" and a junction table called "books_categories". The books table just contains different book titles(might as well be called "products" table). The categories table contains all possible "tags" for a book, like sci-fi, drama, thriller, etc. The junction table contains each book-category relationship. If book number 3 has two tags(lets say sci-fi and thriller), then this table will hold two records with "book_id"=3.

this is representation of the books table:

```
id|name      |author     |publisher
----------------------------------------
1 |some book |some author|some publisher
2 |some book |some author|some publisher
3 |some book |some author|some publisher
```

categories table:

```
category_id|category_name
---------------------------
1          |sci-if
2          |horror
3          |thriller
4          |drama
```

books_categories table:

```
id|book_id|category_id
--------------------------
1 |2      |1
2 |2      |3
3 |3      |1
4 |4      |4
5 |4      |2
```

What i'm trying to do, is to create a query, that selects only those books, that have a specific set of categories associated with them. Let's say, the user wants the site to present all book titles that are **BOTH** sci-fi and drama. Verbally, the query would look like that: "select all book titles that have sci-fi **AND** drama associated with them.

I tried various JOINS and sub-queries, but nothing yields the required result. I manage to construct a query that would be suitable if i had to choose **ONLY ONE CATEGORY**, but not multiple. Please help me solve it :-)

Comment: Note that id in the bc table serves no purpose

Comment: ...In (...) Group by ... having count(*) = number of arguments in In(...)

Comment: Hey..can u please be more specific? I'm new to sql, and cant really figure out what i need from your response :-)

Comment: Go on. There's enough there for you to figure it out.